# Placing a picture in a worksheet, relative to a cell

Tags: vba, excel

How do I place the picture (vSelection) under "data" Sheet Cell U24?

This is placing the picture in the wrong location.

```
Top = Sheets("Data").Range("u24").Top
Left = Sheets("Data").Range("u24").Left

Set oShape = oActive.Shapes.AddPicture(vSelection, True, True, Left, Top, 80, 80)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to appear 'under' cell `U24` you need to get the 'top' of cell `U25`.

`Top = Sheets("Data").Range("U25").Top`

Comment: thank you however it's still placing it in the wrong sheet. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to make sure that 'oActive' is your 'data' sheet.  Or just replace 'oActive' with 'Sheets("Data")'